# javascript if statements executing but blocking each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If statements are being executed but result are not shown, result text is displayed for a fraction of a second and is quickly erased by another result

```
<script>
function validateEmail($email) {
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    return emailReg.test($email);
}

function myFunction() {
    var user = $('#user-name').val();
    var userpass = $('#user-password1').val();
    var userpass1 = $('#user-password2').val();
    var useremail = $('#user-email').val();
    var passMatch = false;
    var nameValid = false;
    var emailValid = false;
    //Check Username availability
    if ($.trim(user) != '') {
        $.post('includes/checkUserName.php', {
            checkUser: user
        }, function(checkData) {
            $('#regErrors').text(checkData);
        });
    }
    //Check Email availability
    if ($.trim(useremail) != '') {
        $.post('includes/checkEmail.php', {
            checkE: useremail
        }, function(checkEmail) {
            $('#regErrors').text(checkEmail);
        });
    }
    if ($.trim(userpass) != userpass1) {
        $('#regErrors').text("Passwords must match")
    }
    if ($.trim(user) == '' || $.trim(userpass) == '' || $.trim(userpass1) == '' || $.trim(useremail) == '') {
        $('#regErrors').text("All fields required")
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are replacing the content upon each post by using the `.text()` method, append a tag instead:

```
$('#regErrors').append($("<p />", {html: checkData}));
$('#regErrors').append($("<p />", {html: checkEmail}));
$('#regErrors').append($("<p />", {html: "Passwords must match"}));
$('#regErrors').append($("<p />", {html: "All fields required"}));
```

Comment: Would it be possible to delete the previous text before the new text is appended?

Comment: This worked  $('#regErrors').append($("<span />", "")); Thanks for your help